# Inno-Setup with foldable components tree

Tags: treeview, inno-setup

I am trying to make a Inno setup with a lot of different components to select (> 50). For this case a foldable tree view like in the picture below would be awesome where I can define which sections should be unfolded by default. (IB4: I can not use NSIS for a couple of other reasons)

It looks like the guys on [http://restools.hanzify.org](http://restools.hanzify.org/article.asp?id=89) found a way how to make it work, but it seems like they modified the inno setup exe (Google Translate) which seems like a really bad idea to me. I tried it anyway but couldn't get it running.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[image: Setup as desired]

Comment: `ComponentsList` is `TNewCheckListBox`, i.e. "list box", not "tree view". So it does not support collapsing. Even the tree lines are custom drawn. - Did you consider splitting the components page to multiple pages? Or adding something like "Customize" button that would display sub-components of a selected component?

Comment: Or add it as a feature request in the newsgroup. They might be able to support it?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle That would be a huge change (changing "list box" to "tree view") that would break existing scripts. So I'm afraid that it's unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. As mentioned I also thought about a custom page but I need to combine any subcategory item with any other so I would have to remember all the selections and then combine them afterwards. I'm to bad in pascal to do so...